# Downloading and saving news articles

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

To be honest, I am pretty new to coding. I want to analyse the articles my local newspaper publishes on ther website. To do that, I have a list of URLs and from that, I want to download and save all the articles published. This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import pickle
import time

def savelist(allurls, dname):
    with open(dname, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(allurls, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

def readlist(dname):
    with open(dname, 'rb') as f:
        return(pickle.load(f))

def turntosoup(liste):
    #turns a list of URLs to a list of soups
    soups = list()
    for url in liste:
        r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
        soups.append(soup)
    return(soups)

def einzelsuppe(url):
    r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
    return(soup)


def gettextdesk(soup):
    #extracts the Text from the Soup and returns a List
    article=(soup.find(class_='g_m_1of2'))
    try:
        hlwithhtml=article.find('h1')
        hl = hlwithhtml.string
    except:
        hl = ''

    try:
        pubdatewithhtml=article.find(class_='publication_date')
        pubdate = pubdatewithhtml.getText(' ', strip=True)
    except:
        pubdate = ''

    try:
        abstractwithhtml=article.find(class_='abstract ')
        abstract=abstractwithhtml.getText(' ', strip=True)
    except:
        abstract = ''

    try:
        contentwithhtml=article.find(class_='content')
        while contentwithhtml.script:
            contentwithhtml.script.decompose()
        content = contentwithhtml.getText(' ', strip=True)
    except:
        content = ''

    newspost = [str(hl), str(abstract), str(content), str(pubdate)]
    return(newspost)

def workonlist(urllist):
    souplist = turntosoup(urllist)
    soups = list()
    for soup in souplist:
        geparst = gettextdesk(soup)
        soups.append(geparst)
    return(soups)

start_time = time.time()

essenurls = readlist('Liste URLs Essen')

def chunker(seq, size):
    # found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks
    return[seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size)]


def abarbeiten(essenurls):
    count = 50
    for teilurls in chunker(essenurls, 50):
        savelist(workonlist(teilurls), 'Essen %d' % count)
        count +=50

abarbeiten(essenurls)

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Where should I change stuff to improve performance? It takes about 1.9 seconds per URL, and i wondered if I could make it faster.

This is the output of `python3 -m cProfile -s cumtime Abrufen.py`:

http://pastebin.com/2yLXGx3s (i couldn't post it here because of the character limit)

Here is a list of URLs as an example:

```
essenurls = ['http://www.derwesten.de/staedte/essen/schweinekopf-an-moschee-in-essen-altendorf-befestigt-id12200572.html','http://www.derwesten.de/staedte/essen/vor-drei-jahren-verschwand-pierre-pahlke-aus-essen-id12201302.html','http://www.derwesten.de/staedte/essen/essen-packt-an-geht-riesenbaerenklau-an-die-wurzel-id12201120.html']
```

Comment: Please note that German language variable/function names makes it way harder for us to review your code. Also including the output of `python3 -m cProfile -s cumtime read_articles.py` will help potential reviewers to see which functions take the most time and should therefore be more optimized

Answer (score 1):

#### Repetition and potential for bug hiding

```
try:
    hlwithhtml=article.find('h1')
    hl = hlwithhtml.string
except:
    hl = ''

try:
    pubdatewithhtml=article.find(class_='publication_date')
    pubdate = pubdatewithhtml.getText(' ', strip=True)
except:
    pubdate = ''

try:
    abstractwithhtml=article.find(class_='abstract ')
    abstract=abstractwithhtml.getText(' ', strip=True)
except:
    abstract = ''

try:
    contentwithhtml=article.find(class_='content')
    while contentwithhtml.script:
        contentwithhtml.script.decompose()
    content = contentwithhtml.getText(' ', strip=True)
except:
    content = ''
```

**Potential for bug hiding**

`except` without argument swallows **any** exception, that is if you mistype for example `hlithhtml`, `h1` will always be empty and you will not be notified of any error.

**Repetition**

You try an action and if it fails resort to a default value. Also these blocks of code

```
    pubdatewithhtml=article.find(class_='publication_date')
    pubdate = pubdatewithhtml.getText(' ', strip=True)
```

---

```
    abstractwithhtml=article.find(class_='abstract ')
    abstract=abstractwithhtml.getText(' ', strip=True)
```

Are very similar only `class_` changes.

I suggest you re-organize this code using:

```
def action_with_default(action, exception, default):
    try:
        return action()
    except exception:
        return default


def find_class(article, class_):
    x = article.find(class_=class_)
    return x.getText(' ', strip=True)
```

This should save you a lot of duplication.